# Add/remove EventHandler multiple times in WPF

Tags: wpf, event-handling

If I add (or remove) the same EventHandler to an Event multiple times, is that "bad"? Is anything happening internally which would cause problems here?  (I am implementing data validation on a TextBox, which will turn on/off a MouseDoubleClick handler as the TB content becomes in/valid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing really happens when you try to *unsubscribe* from event multiple times.

When you want to *subscribe* to event with your handler you can make sure it's not already *subscribed*. You should do that. Because **it's possible to *subscribe* multiple times.** of course only if it's not something you want to do...

What happens when you *subscribe* to the event twice with same handler? It's simple... handler is twice in event's `InvocationList` so it's called twice. When you subscribe again then it's called three times... every time the event is raised subscribed Handlers in `InvocationList` are called.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937181/c-sharp-pattern-to-prevent-an-event-handler-hooked-twice) ...as you can see... It's duplicate of at least two already asked questions. So there are many answers :)