# C#: Reset Controls in a Panel (WinForms)

Tags: c#, controls, panel

What is a quick way to reset all the `Controls` inside a panel to their initial states (Compile-time state)? I have `TextBoxes`, `RadioButtons`, `ComboBoxes`, and `CheckBoxes` to reset. I'd like them to reset to the values when the program first ran. I'd like a solution that does *not involve looping or recursion* mainly because I don't want to reimplement the same thing over again when I start witha new project. I'm simply finding a set of methods to call that will do the job. Are there any?

Comment: What, for example, would be the 'initial state' of a TextBox? Do you simply want to clear the text, or do you want to reset ALL properties of it into some default value?

Same goes with other controls?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for an abracadabra magic code.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? MVC? Maybe just destroy the form and show a new instance?

Comment: @Sach I edited my post. :)

Comment: @LarsTech just trying to find a simpler way, really.

Comment: @AustinFrench WinForms. How do I do that?

Comment: just create a new form instance?

Answer (score 2):

Your controls have no compile time state, because state is a runtime concept.

I think you mean you want controls re-initialized to the state as shown on your property sheets. This state is applied by the generated code located in `InitializeComponent`, so to re-apply that state, you could just call it again.

The only problem is `InitializeComponent` also wires up events, and you probably don't want to do that twice. You could possibly work around this by deregistering all of your events before calling it, or by deduplicating the invocation list afterward (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937181/c-sharp-pattern-to-prevent-an-event-handler-hooked-twice)).

I don't recommend any of this. The best approach would be to write your own method that sets the properties the way you want them, one by one. Sometimes ya gotta write code.