# How to check a eventhandler is registered

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a class X and this class have a event: EventX.

And I have a class B, I register event EventX of objectX to a eventhandler HandlerB of class B.

```
X objectX = X.GetStaticObject();
objectX.EventX += HandlerB;
```

How to check EventX of objectX contained eventhandler HandlerB. Thanks.

**Notes:** objectX is a static global which event can be registered from anywhere with any objects which are not object B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check that specifically your HandlerB was registered, you can use [Delegate.GetInvocationList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) method to get appropriate info.

**EDIT:**

After V4Vendetta comment I tried to compile code and it failed. I slightly changed it.

To be able to do that check, method Test should be added to X (I assume that it's static, otherwise use this instead of X):

```
public static void Test(Delegate delegateToTest)
{
   if (X.EventX != null)
   {
       foreach (Delegate existingHandler in X.EventX.GetInvocationList())
       {
           if (existingHandler == delegateToTest)
           {
               // registered
           }
       }
    }
}
```

And then test from somewhere where HandlerB is accessible:

```
X.Test(new EventHandler(HandlerB));
```

Comment: @V4Vendetta: you are right. I did not check it in VS and completely forget that it may cause error. However I edited code to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not null, it is registered (though it might be with an empty handler).

```
if(objectX.EventX != null)
{
  // registered!
}
```

As far as I know, you can't tell *what* is registered with it. Being able to would defeat the point of having an event in the first place (decoupling code and double dispatch).

Comment: However, it can registered from anywhere, because objectX is a global object (static). Thanks.

Comment: I add more info. Please help me. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent an event handler to be registered twice for the same event, you could remove it before you register it - something like this:

```
objectX.EventX -= HandlerB; 
objectX.EventX += HandlerB;
```

This can be done in the registering code, or even in the event itself. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399648/803335) for details.

*Note*: removing HandlerB should not fail, even if it was not registered before! (Unless somebody changed the `remove` part in an explicit event definition to do so.)