# C# increasing Memory on camera image processing

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have a problem with increasing memory. I have an image, that comes from a camera. The image is processed by a function with unmanaged code. If the expected pattern could not be found, this function takes a long time (some seconds). If the pattern can be found it returns a result very fast (some ms).

I tried to start the postprocessing in a new `Thread` and `Abort` it after 200ms. So far this works. Now I have the problem, that my memory grows. Maybe the `using` clause doesn't work as expected and the image is kept in memory...

```
private void ImageWorker()
{
    while (_imageWorkerRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var img = CameraHelper.GetImage())
            {
                var waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                ProcessResult result = null;
                var thd = new Thread(() => {
                    result = UnManagedImageProcessor.Process(img);
                    waiter.Set();
                });
                thd.Start();
                waiter.WaitOne(200);
                if (thd.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running || result == null)
                {
                    thd.Abort();
                    while (thd.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted) new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(10);
                }

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayImage = img);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Does the `GC` work fine on aborted Threads? I think maybe this is my problem...

**Solutiuon:**

I changed my code to the following. Now I have two parallel tasks. The first is getting images and check, if processing is available.

If it is, the image is provided to this `ImageProcessing` task. That displays image only on `Success` (then processing is fast and each picture can be processed).

If processing is not successfull it takes some time and the image is displayed only as live image (by `ImageWorker`).

```
private readonly object _imageLock = new object();
private ExtendedImage _sharedProcessingImage;
private readonly ManualResetEvent _processingWaiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private bool _processingWaits = false;

private void ImageWorker()
{
    while (_imageWorkerRunning) {
        try {
            var img = CameraHelper.GetImage();
            if (_processingWaits) {
                //processing available --> process image
                lock (_imageLock) {
                    _sharedProcessingImage = img;
                }
                _processingWaits = false;
                _processingWaiter.Set();
            }
            else {
                //Processing in progress --> Only display image
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayImage = img);
            }
            new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(50);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            _log.Error(e);
        }
    }
}

private void ImageProcessing()
{
    while (_imageWorkerRunning) {
        _processingWaits = true;
        _processingWaiter.WaitOne();
        _processingWaiter.Reset();
        lock (_imageLock) {
            try {
                result = UnManagedImageProcessor.Process(_sharedProcessingImage);
                // ... handle result
                if(result.Succeeded) Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayImage = _sharedProcessingImage);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                _log.Error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to use the result of `waiter.WaitOne(200)` instead of checking the ThreadState and the result variable. If the WaitOne times out, the result should not be touched. (cross threading access)

Comment: What does `DisplayImage = img` do? is it a property with set logic?

Comment: My guess is you're leaking GDI resources.  But there's not enough code here to tell.  As Jeroen asked, for example, what does DisplayImage do?  Or UnManagedImageProcessor.Process?

Comment: Aborting threads is bad. What if method is in middle of allocating some memory and you abort it? Of course it won't be released = problems. Instead you could let thread to finish its job, but limit number of threads you allow to continue working in background. Or just wait for one but fill images asynchronously. As for synchronization `Monitor.Enter`/`Leave` is [preferable](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking).

Comment: Also, you should add a `try/catch` in your threadmethod.

Comment: Hi there, as Jeroen mentioned the DisplayImage is a property with set logic (for showing the live image). I will try the approach Sinatr mentioned and tell you if this works better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I propose to you is to use [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

To display the images you can use a locker, every time the UI is idle you lock the object, get the last image and dispose the previus one. Also, everytime a image is processed you lock the object and set the var to the last one.

Display logic:

```
readonly object lastProcessdImageLocker = new object();
Bitmap lastProcessdImage;

//Every time a image process is done:
lock(lastProcessdImageLocker)
    lastProcessdImage = imageJustProcessed;

//Every time the UI thread is idle
lock(lastProcessdImageLocker)
    myPictureboxImage = lastProcessdImage;
//Here you should also dispose the previus myPictureboxImage so you prevent your memory usage to grow fast!
```

[See this post for more info about WPF and also WinForm render loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991949/how-to-make-a-render-loop-in-wpf)

Sample code of the use of BlockingCollection to consume (process) camera images:

```
BlockingCollection<Bitmap> cameraImages = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();
```

//use another theard to fill up the cameraImages, like that:
//cameraImages.Add(CameraHelper.GetImage());

```
void StartProcess()
{
    if (processImageThread== null || !processImageThread.IsAlive)
    {
        processImageThread= new Thread(ProcessLoop);
        processImageThread.Name = "ProcessLoop";
        processImageThread.IsBackground = true;
        processImageThread.Start();
        Console.TraceInformation("ProcessLoop started");
    }
}
private void ProcessLoop()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (img in cameraImages.GetConsumingEnumerable(CancelProcessing.Token))
        {
            // Do your stuff               
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ProcessLoop OperationCanceledException.");
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

If your cameraImages count grows too fast (getting out of memory), you need to reduce the process time or stop the camera for some time.

Comment: looks great. I'll try this. I'll give a feedback tomorrow (when I'm at work again)!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That helped me to come to a solution with separate processing loop.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. You used BlockingCollection?

Comment: I updated my question and added my solution (as you can see). I just used the approach of independent image-processing loop.