# Issue with editing value in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, user-controls

[image]

This combobox is part of a larger User Control written in C# that I am embedding in another application. When selecting a value from the combobox and after it loses focus, I cannot come back and actually edit the displayed text. I have to either delete all of the text and manually enter text or select a new value. The combobox is not bound to any source, and the values were added through Items.Add. There are no events tied to the combobox either. Is there some setting I am not aware of? I have looked, and searched Google, and can't find anything.

Comment: That sounds strange. Is it only happening for this one combobox?

Comment: All of the comboboxes on the User Control exhibit the same behavior. The comboboxes are part of a panel on the user control, but I wouldn't expect that to be an issue either. I am wondering if the app I am embedding into is causing this behavior.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136975/has-an-event-handler-already-been-added) can help to find out if the host application is adding a handler.. Is it Winforms btw?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is WinForms. I'll look into it adding a handler. I was going to email the api support group for the software as well. I am guessing they can shed some light on this too.