# Access event handler list c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

Is it possible to access list of all handlers/delegates attached to event from outside of class. What i need to do is test if handlers/delegates attached successfully to various events .

Comment: I have been reading up topic and apparently it should be possible with use of reflection, however it will be first time using reflections for me so guiding would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible from outside the class, primarily due to scope. Do you have access to the class? If so, see the answers here:

[Has an event handler already been added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136975/has-an-event-handler-already-been-added)