# How to get function names which bind to the delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

For example, with winform, I drag a button named button1 on the winform.

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Alert);
```

the answer is how can I get the function names bound to button1 in code.

I want to get the function names,then use names to find source codes about button1, when user click button1, I will give the source code about button1.

Comment: its not an exact dup of [Has an event handler already been added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136975/has-an-event-handler-already-been-added) - but that has the answers - google is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use reflection and `GetInvocationList` method. Below a sample that retrieves names of a handlers for a button.Click and puts them in a list:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        this.button1.Click += Button1_Click1;

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = button1.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = propertyInfo.GetValue(button1, new object[] { }) as EventHandlerList;
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        var eventKey = fieldInfo.GetValue(button1);
        var eventHandler = eventHandlerList[eventKey] as Delegate;
        Delegate[] invocationList = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

        var names = new List<string>();

        foreach (var handler in invocationList)
        {
            names.Add(handler.GetMethodInfo().Name);
        }
    }
```

This approach can be easily applied to other events as well. You will have to replace `"EventClick"` to whatever event you want to test:

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Comment: The question was tagged as winforms. I'm not sure, but I think you are referring to wpf. Can't find the fields you mentioned in `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class. Anyway, nice solution.

Comment: @RenéVogt No, that's definitely winforms solution. Tested in winforms enfironment.

Comment: Ok. Upvoted, because you don't need an own inherited class like in my solution.

Comment: Thank you your answer. I have many controls like button1,and each control may have not only one function bind to event,and the event may not be Click.So I need think about many problities and write codes for every control?need your deep answers,Thank you again~

Answer (score 0):

That's not so easy. Events declared in a class only expose `add` and `remove` to users of that class. You can access the invocation list of the event only from inside the class.

So one way you may achieve this is to inherit your own `MyButton` class like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    private event EventHandler MyClick;
    public new event EventHandler Click
    {
        add
        {
            MyClick += value;
            base.Click += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            MyClick -= value;
            base.Click -= value;
        }
    }
    public Delegate[] GetClickHandlers()
    {
        return MyClick?.GetInvocationList();
    }
}
```

So I create a new `Click` event that wraps the `base.Click` event and stores the invocation list in an extra event.

You can than get the names of the associated handlers like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
        button1.GetClickHandlers().Select(h => h.Method.Name)));
```

But now that I see this code, you could probably store/remove the `value`s passed to `add` and `remove` in a separate list instead of using `MyClick`, but the idea is the same.

Your main problem is that you cannot call `GetInvocationList()` on `Button.Click`.

Comment: so sorry,this can't solve my problem.Because I have too many controls like button1,I can't rewrite each of them.Thank you all the same ~