# UWP ScrollViewer - Differentiate between user scrolling and programmatic scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, scroll, uwp, scrollviewer

I have an application where I need to take a certain action when the user gets to a certain place in a `ScrollViewer`.  This action sometimes includes scrolling the `ScrollViewer` to a different location programmatically.

In order to moniter the user's scrolling action, I am listening for the `ViewChanged` event of the `ScrollViewer`.  The issue is that when I scroll progrmatically from within the `ViewChanged` event handler, that same event handler ends up getting called again, causing undesired additional scrolling to happen.

I have tried creating a custom method to remove the event handler before calling `ScrollViewer.ChangeView()`, but this seems to have no effect.

Can anyone come up with a way around this issue, or a way to differentiate the user's scrolling action from my programmatic one?

```
private void MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (conditionals) 
    {
        ScrollTo(location);
    }
}

private void ScrollTo(double offset)
{
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null);
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged += MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, unfortunately, not possible to determine what triggered a `ViewChanged` event.  It is however possible to solve this problem.

The issue is that `ChangeView()` is asynchronous, so re-adding the event handler immediately after calling `ChangeView` is too soon.  `ChangeView` will raise a bunch of `ViewChanged` events with a final one where `e.IsIntermediate == false`; only once that happens should you re-hook the event handler.  The best way to handle this might be to use a temporary event handler that waits for that `e.IsIntermediate == false` and then re-hooks the original handler.

To prevent the user from interacting with the `ScrollViewer` during the execution of `ChangeView`, the scroll and zoom modes can be temporarily disabled.

Finally, if the user is manipulating the `ScrollViewer` when the conditionals are met, that manipulation needs to be [canceled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx) before calling `ScrollTo()`.

**EDIT:**  In my implementation, an issue arose where because of the number of times these handlers were called, event handlers were added more than once.  To combat this, I've taken the simple strategy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065771/2517147).

```
private void MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (!conditionals) return;

    if (e.IsIntermediate) 
    {
        var uiElement = MyScrollViewer.Content as UIElement;
        uiElement?.CancelDirectManipulations();
    }

    ScrollTo(location);
}

private void Temporary_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsIntermediate) return;
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= Temporary_ViewChanged;
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged += MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged;

    MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    MyScrollViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled;
}

private void ScrollTo(double offset)
{
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= MyScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= Temporary_ViewChanged;
    MyScrollViewer.ViewChanged += Temporary_ViewChanged;

    MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    MyScrollViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Disabled;

    MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null);
}
```